# webservice get body(response) issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

This is the error that I get when I am trying to hit web service

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:webservice.com/abc
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

statuse is 200 ok

```
$.ajax({
    url :"http://webservice/Demo.php",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    error:function(response){
        alert("error");
    }, 
    success:function(response){
        alert("success");
    }                     
});
```

Comment: Well, make sure the proper [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) *are* being sent then.

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I think it has to do with cross-domain requests which isn't allowed basically.